# Push info to the store in a success after an ajax request in ember

Tags: ember.js, store

I'm new with ember and I wanted to know if it was possible to push some information that I've got back from my server into the store in ember.

I've tried this :

```
            $.ajax({
            url: host,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            accepts: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                login.reset();
                console.log("DEBUG: Login Succeed");
                model: function() {
                    this.store.push() {
                        id: data.session.user.id,
                        username: data.session.user.username    
                    }
                }
                login.transitionTo('home');
            },
            error: function() {
                login.reset();
                login.set('loginFailed', true);
                console.log("DEBUG: Login Failed");
            }
        });
```

But obviously I'm wrong, and I don't really know how to do it :/

thanks for your help !!

EDIT:

Here is the new working code. I just forgot a small thing... such as the name of the model..

```
            $.ajax({
            url: host,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            accepts: 'application/json',
            success: function(data) {
                login.reset();
                console.log("DEBUG: Login Succeed");
                    login.store.push('user', {
                        id: data.session.user.id,
                        username: data.session.user.username,
                        firstname: data.session.user.firstname,
                        lastname: data.session.user.lastname,
                        email: data.session.user.email,
                        domainid: data.session.user.domain,
                        role: data.session.user.role,
                        status: data.session.user.status
                    });
                login.transitionTo('home');
            },
            error: function() {
                login.reset();
                login.set('loginFailed', true);
                console.log("DEBUG: Login Failed");
            }
        });
```

Comment: try using something like this: this.store.load(YourModel, {id: data.session.user.id, username: data.session.user.username})

Comment: Is this your real code?  Fix it so it is valid JavaScript.  The `push` function should take two parameters.

Comment: Omg, I'm retard, I didn't see that I've put my id and username oustide of my push >< ...

Anyway, it see to be that I've a problem with the function in the model.. now (Look the edit)